# How to Change to Wrap Terminal in WebStrom

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, ide

I am not findind how to change the terminal in webstrom to wrap terminal.
i found it for vs code
https://www.warp.dev/

I tried it as i felt it would be good to learn it

Comment: You can't but you can add another command line app like https://fig.io. I use it with my terminal: https://tabby.sh and my JetBrains IDEs....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible in WebStorm and other IntelliJ-based IDEs because it's really hard to implement this feature, as was said [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286743).